# Unable to get graphql response from server that's running on local

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, express-graphql

I have a mongodb server setup which on running the below command starts on port 3000

```
npm run start
```

I also a graphql server which on running the below command starts at port 4000

```
npm run start-graphql
```

the scripts of my package.json is as below

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start-graphql": "nodemon graphqlserver.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
const db = mongoose.connection;


db.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log("Backend Database connected");
});


app.use(express.json({ limit: '2mb'}));

const photosRouter = require('./routes/photos');
app.use('/images', photosRouter)


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started at port 3000');
})
```

**graphqlserver.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const express_graphql = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
const { loadSchemaSync } =  require('@graphql-tools/load');
const { GraphQLFileLoader } = require('@graphql-tools/graphql-file-loader');
const { addResolversToSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');

const getResolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');

// GraphQL schema
const combinedSchema = loadSchemaSync(
    path.join(__dirname, './graphql/schemas/*.graphql'),
    {
      loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()],
    }
  );
const schema = addResolversToSchema({
    schema: combinedSchema,
    resolvers: Object.assign({}, getResolvers())
  });

// Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint
const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
}));
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Express GraphQL Server Now Running On localhost:4000/graphql'));
```

when I call the rest api's normally either through postman or curl it returns the response as expected.

For eg: `http://localhost:3000/images` returns me an array of objects

But When I want to call (using axios) the same via the graphql server (which is running on port 4000 ),
I get response as null.
I have no clue why this is happening.
Please check the below screenshot for your reference
[image]

Note: For better clarity please check the codebase link
https://github.com/yaswankar/G-photos-backend

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Request: Please help by giving an upvote so that it could better reach to those who could help.

**Edit:**

New Error screenshot
[image]

Comment: You're basically asking "why isn't my project working", which would make it too broad of a question. What have you done to debug this issue? Does the request reach the correct resolver, for instance?

Comment: I agree but that's becoz I don't have a clue of what's happening. I tried checking if that was a cors issue etc but no luck. Everything seems to be fine in the network tab. But its not able to reach the resolvers function of graphql

Comment: FWIW, you don't have a resolver for `photo`.

Comment: There is one, please check the repository

Comment: No, there's not. Really. There's a `PhotoQuery` resolver (which I assume you _think_ will be used for `photos`, but won't), but _not_ a `photo` resolver. Add one and you'll see it will get called.

Comment: oh I partially get it, so where do I need to add it?

Comment: to the [root resolver](https://github.com/yaswankar/G-photos-backend/blob/master/graphql/resolvers/root.js)

Comment: I added it [here](https://github.com/yaswankar/G-photos-backend/blob/master/graphql/resolvers/photos/index.js). Now it hits the resolver function and they are working but I landed up with this error. I have added the screenshot in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the main issue by adding the query block inside photos resolver

```
Query: {
    photo: photosContext,
  },
```

The other error was resolved by processing the response instead of sending the raw data to the hyper class

```
async function getActivePhotos(parent, args, req) {
    try {
        const activePhotos = await photoService.getActivePhotos(req).then(resp => resp.data.map(item => item)); // Process and mapping data
        return activePhotos;
    } catch (error) {
        // logger.error(__filename + ': Failed to get response for getActivePhotos, err=' + JSON.stringify(error));
        return new GraphQLError(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
}
```